# Properties of a some unbounded convex set

Tags: real-analysis

Let $A$ and $B$ be a convex compact subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$, $n\geqslant2$.
Define the set of rays
$$
C = \{a+bt: \quad a\in A, \; b\in B, \; t\in[0, \infty)\}\subset\mathbb{R}^n.
$$

1. Let $0\notin B$, where $0$ is the origin of $\mathbb{R}^n$.
   Prove that the set $C$ is closed.
2. Let $0\in \partial B$, where $\partial B$ is the boundary of $B$.
   Prove that the set $C$ is not necessarily closed by constructing
   an example of the sets $A$ and $B$ and a sequence $c_n\in C$, such that
   $c_n\to c$, where $c\notin C$ .

So far, I have only been able to prove that (i) $C$ is convex, and that (ii) if $0$
is an interior point of $B$, then $C=\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: The second question actually gives you a hint on the first one. Recall that a subset of a metric space is closed if and only if it contains all its limits! Let $(c_n)$ be a sequence of elements $c_n\in C$ that converges to some $c\in\mathbb{R^n}$. Try to proof that $c\in C$. Hint: Write $c_n=a_n +b_n t_n$.

Comment: Another hint may be that compact subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$ are sequentially compact as you will have to work with subsequences. But dont worry while you do! Your $c_n$ converge, so if you find a convergent subsequence the limits agree!

Comment: For the second question consider $A=\left\lbrace(x,y)\ \big|\ x^2+y^2\leq1\right\rbrace\subset\mathbb{R}^2$,  the disk of radius $1$ around the origin in the plane. Let $B=\left\lbrace(x,y)\ \big|\ x^2+(y-1)^2\leq1\right\rbrace\subset\mathbb{R}^2$ be the according disc with radius $1$ around the point $P=(0,1)$. Why is $C$ not closed? Observe that to reason for openness you havev to take a series $b_n$ in $B$ that converges to $0$ and a sequence $t_n$ in $\left[0,\infty\right)$ converging to $\infty$

Comment: WhenYouHaveNoClue, thank you very much for your answer.